# Calling a llvm pass outside of a pass

Tags: c++, llvm, analysis

I am new to LLVM and C++ and was trying to write some code to perform static analysis. My static analysis needs access to memory dependence info, which in LLVM can be obtained using MemoryDependenceAnalysis. This analysis generates an object of type MemoryDependenceResults, which is precisely what I need. The only ways I've seen this object being obtained, though, is through an LLVM pass and that's not something I want. My impression is you have to write a pass to be able to use  an existing pass. I was wondering is that true? Can I call a pass outside of a pass, i.e. regular code? Or alternatively can a llvm pass be invoked programmatically without needing to run the opt command?

What I need is a way to obtain this MemoryDependenceResults object in my program (which is not a pass) and then perform some more manipulations to it.

Comment: I'm not sure, but shouldn't you be able to create a pass manager, add that pass and then get the result? Here is the new PM (only available from LLVM 12 or 13 on, idk): https://llvm.org/docs/NewPassManager.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried that and it doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can create a PassManager instance anywhere, add the pass into the manager and run it. Here are two PassManagers can be used - [legacy](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1legacy_1_1PassManager.html) or [the new one](http://llvm.org/docs/NewPassManager.html). To make it simple, I recommend you try the legacy one first:

```
legacy::PassManager passManager;
passManager.add(new MemoryDependenceWrapperPass());
passManager.run(*module);
```

Second, if you wish to run a transform pass, you call it. But if you wish to run an analysis pass, you need at least a wrapper pass to get the analysis result since the API [getAnalysis()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Pass.html#a4863e5e463fb79955269fbf7fbf52b80) is only available in a pass. (You can copy and rename MemoryDependenceWrapperPass to your version.)